# xpath query to select data in range

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382919</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130114164038</LogDateTime>            
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301161640382920</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130115154040</LogDateTime>           
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
  <LogID>5678201301161640382921</LogID>
  <LogDateTime>20130116164042</LogDateTime>          
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>

strXpathQuery = @"/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime/text()>=[starts-with(. , '20130115') and LogDateTime/text()<=starts-with(. , '20130116')]";
```

**I have to write xpath query to select logdata in range where LogDateTime starts with 20130115 to 20130117
I am trying above query but fails to get data**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) >= 20130115 
                              and substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) <= 20130116]
```

If you want to include 20130117 items in the selection, you would change the "20130116" value to "20130117".

Comment: JL above query gives me zero nodes

Comment: Do you get any nodes if you just try `/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime]`? Is the double "t" in "Writter" intentional?

Comment: It locates 2 nodes when I use it an XSLT. Could you post above the actual code you're using to run these XPath queries, with my suggested query included?  What are you plugging the XPath into?