# How to Get Data In Between Range of Date with XPath Query

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AppXmlLogWritter>    
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301211226306349434819061642515658</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>**20130121**122630</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PMLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PMLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PMLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PMLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PMLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301211226306349434819063542617610</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>**20130121**122630</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PMLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PMLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PMLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PMLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PMLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301211226306349434819065542731198</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>**20130121**122630</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PMLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PMLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PMLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PMLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PMLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201301211226306349434819067442849561</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>**20130117**122630</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PMLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PMLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PMLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PMLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PMLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

From the above XmL file i want to read the xml document in between the range. such I implement the windows form with datetimepicker control for From Date and To Date and one submit button when i choose date from FROM DATE and also from the TO DATE it display the date into list view from these from tow different date
for this i have write the code as

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
 XmlElement objXmlRoot = objXmldoc.DocumentElement;
if (chkBoxFromDate.Checked && chkBoxToDate.Checked)
            {
                strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogDateTime >='" +  dateTimePickerFromDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' and LogDateTime <='" + dateTimePickerToDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "']";
}
}
```

I use this query to display data but it shows me blank data.

Comment: Is this homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435803/xpath-query-to-select-data-in-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting a feeling of déjà vu.  Didn't I just [answer this question for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436034/1945651)?

```
strXpathQuery = "/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) > " + 
    dateTimePickerFromDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + 
    " and substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) <= " + 
    dateTimePickerToDate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "]";
```

Or formatted a little more nicely

```
strXpathQuery = 
   string.Format("/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) > {0:yyyyMMdd} and substring(LogDateTime, 1, 8) <= {1:yyyyMMdd}]", 
   dateTimePickerFromDate.Value, dateTimePickerToDate.Value);
```